# why using a hashmap (sNotesProjectionMap in NotePad sample) before a query?

Tags: android, hashmap, android-contentprovider

why do we need to set a projectionMap with SQLiteQueryBuilder ? For example, we set this HashMap :

```
sNotesProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
sNotesProjectionMap.put(Notes._ID, Notes._ID);
sNotesProjectionMap.put(Notes.TITLE, Notes.TITLE);
sNotesProjectionMap.put(Notes.NOTE, Notes.NOTE);
sNotesProjectionMap.put(Notes.CREATED_DATE, Notes.CREATED_DATE);
sNotesProjectionMap.put(Notes.MODIFIED_DATE, Notes.MODIFIED_DATE);
```

and in the "query", we also specify the projection, selection etc. from the Activity, so what the point to do this hashmap first?

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
        String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(NOTES_TABLE_NAME);

    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case NOTES:
        qb.setProjectionMap(sNotesProjectionMap);
        break;

    case NOTE_ID:
        qb.setProjectionMap(sNotesProjectionMap);
        qb.appendWhere(Notes._ID + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
        break;

    //...
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);

    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the documentation for [setprojectionmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setProjectionMap%28java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29) . It does translations from application column names to database columns.  Hashmap will have the translation.

The key in the map is the column name the application will use and the value is the column name in the database.

They are identical in the NotePadProvider in your example, but they could differ if the name of a column in the database changed and you wanted to keep the change transparent to applications using the content provider.

For example, if the database column name of the "title" field (which is stored in Notes.TITLE) changed to "content", a new constant Notes.CONTENT could be created and the projection insertion would look like:

```
sNotesProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
...
sNotesProjectionMap.put(Notes.TITLE, Notes.CONTENT);
...
```

Comment: if you have renamed a column in your database, but application is still using older name, then you could map the column name used by application to the column name used by the database. So that they can continue to operate without change in application.

Comment: thanks, okay so if the database's column name has changed, how the map will recognize the new name in the database (how the old name in the map will match the new name in the database) ?

Comment: using the hashmap, the key in hashmap is the application recognized column name and the value is the database recognized column name